# Mocking JwtDecoder Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-security-6

I've custom annotation, which is used in several controllers:

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "@applicationUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(#this.getSubject()).getId()")
public @interface CurrentUserId {

}
```

Also I've JwtEncoder:

```
@Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        final JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(keys.getPublicKey()).privateKey(keys.getPrivateKey()).build();
        final JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource);
    }
```

And JwtDecoder:

```
@Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(keys.getPublicKey()).build();
    }
```

My custom static method serves for making mocked calls:

```
public static ResultActions makeMockMvcRequest(final MockMvc mockMvc,
                                                   final HttpMethod requestType,
                                                   final String endpoint,
                                                   final Map<String, Object> params,
                                                   final Object body,
                                                   final User user) throws Exception {
        final var requestBuilder = defineRequestBuilder(requestType, endpoint);
        addBodyIfExists(body, requestBuilder);
        addUserIfExists(user, requestBuilder);
        return mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .params(convertToMultiValueMap(params)));
    }

    private static MockHttpServletRequestBuilder defineRequestBuilder(final HttpMethod requestType, final String endpoint) {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder;
        if (POST.equals(requestType)) {
            requestBuilder = post(endpoint);
        } else if (GET.equals(requestType)) {
            requestBuilder = get(endpoint);
        } else if (PUT.equals(requestType)) {
            requestBuilder = put(endpoint);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported HTTP request type: " + requestType);
        }
        return requestBuilder;
    }

    private static void addBodyIfExists(final Object body, final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder) {
        if (body != null) {
            requestBuilder.content(asJsonString(body));
        }
    }

    private static void addUserIfExists(final User user, final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder) {
        if (user != null) {
            final String[] roles = user.getRoles().stream()
                    .map(Role::name)
                    .distinct()
                    .toArray(String[]::new);

            final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
                    .map(role -> (GrantedAuthority) role::name)
                    .toList();

            requestBuilder
                    .with(user(user.getEmail()).roles(roles))
                    .with(jwt().jwt(j -> j.subject(user.getEmail()).tokenValue("strong-token").build()).authorities(authorities));
        }
    }
```

But when I try to make a mock MVC call, I'm getting following error:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method getId() on null context object
```

How can I mock decoder in order to have resolved given user's ID? Or is there better and more convenient way to achieve mocking goal?

Comment: From what I can see here, your implementation is not following OAuth2 best practices, which almost certainly exposes it to severe security vulnerabilities. For instance, it is very suspicious to have both a JWT encoder and a JWT decoder in the same app. This could make sense only on an authorization server, but I believe you are trying to implement a resource server (REST API secured with Bearer Authorization header).  I suggest you have a look at my tutorials, [starting from there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials)

Comment: @ch4mp, so nice described and explained in your tutorials, but could you please collaborate more on why authorization server and resource server cannot be the same app?

Comment: It can, and actually, it is very frequently the case (most authorization servers expose an API for user administration). But having a standalone authorization server allows to achieve SSO (Single Sign On): many apps sharing the same authorization server => a user having an opened session on this authorization server won't need to login again. Also, the security is pretty different on the two (authorization servers need sessions, resource servers don't)

Comment: Considering the very small footprint of native apps, I advise you to separate your OAuth2 actors in different apps. Easier to understand, easier to configure, easier to scale.

Comment: I forgot the most important: as a beginner, you should really consider picking an existing authorization server rather than writing your own (Keycloak is a frequent choice to install on your infrastructure, Auth0, Okta and Amazon Cognito are just samples of the many cloud offers). I personally never have built an authorization server so far: this is way too much work and a way too much sensitive layer in the information system.

Answer (score 0):

However, if someone interested in my approach, then after hours of debugging I've already found a solution:

1. You have to specify bean for loading user by username:

   @TestConfiguration
   public class SecurityMockConfiguration {

   ```
   @Bean
   public UserDetailsService applicationUserDetailsService() {
       return username -> Stream.of(NEW_USER, FIRST_STUDENT, SECOND_STUDENT, INSTRUCTOR, ADMIN)
               .filter(actor -> Objects.equals(username, actor.getEmail()))
               .findFirst()
               .map(ApplicationUserDetails:: new)
               .orElse(new ApplicationUserDetails(new User()));
   }
   ```

   }
2. Add mocked Jwt for you mockMvc:

   ```
       if (user != null) {
           final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getRoles().stream()
                   .map(role -> (GrantedAuthority) () -> "ROLE_" + role.name())
                   .toList();
           requestBuilder.with(jwt().jwt(j -> j.subject(user.getEmail())).authorities(authorities));
       }
   ```

After that you will be able to make requests based on some user:

```
makeMockMvcRequest(mockMvc, GET, COURSE_ENDPOINT, FIRST_STUDENT)
                                    .andExpect(responseBody().containsObjectsAsJson(userCourses, UserCourseDto.class))
```